# AngularJS - Explicitly see template path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble with routing when using some third-party JavaScript files. The routing works fine without the third party JS files, but with them being called the routing breaks, yielding errors such as:

> angular.js:13424 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: app/views/_header.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)

...Except app/views/_header.html is the correct path as viewed from index.html. This seems to imply that the root somehow has changed with the third party library, so I'd like visibility as to what it sees as the root of the path when it fails on $compile:tpload.

Is there some way to view this information?

**Edit**

Folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

Some reference in **app.js**:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/Home',
        {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
        })
    .when('/PasswordReset',
        {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/passwordReset.html',
            controller: 'ResetRequestController as vm',
            //requireAdLogin: true,
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
        })
    .when('/UserSearch',
        {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/userSearch.html',
            controller: 'UserSearchController as vm',
            //requireAdLogin: true,
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home' });
```

Note, **this works when not using the third-party JS** (Adal.js and Adal-Angular.js).

Comment: The path should be relative to the JavaScript/TypeScript file, not the host index.html

Comment: @JuanMendes Oh? Which file, then? app.js? The library files for angularjs (I hope not, or else that will create an incredibly screwy folder structure)? Something else? And why would it have worked before, relative to index.html?

Comment: Relative to the file that is referencing `template`. You have to show what code is including header.html; it's hard to make suggestions when your question  show sno code at all.

Comment: @JuanMendes Went ahead and included the folder structure and the code with all of the path references.

Comment: I don't see an example that is calling `header.html` which is where you said the error is. Also, what is the version of angular?

Comment: To clarify the original question when I said "yielding errors such as" I'm getting that for every reference in app.js when using the third-party JS files. The header was just one example. And the version is 1.5.5. I absolutely can change AngularJS versions.